# Independent random variables and $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_k)$ be a sequence of independent random variables, all defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Fix a positive integer $n$ and define
$$
C_n=\sigma(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n),\quad D_n=\sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\cdots).
$$

Here is my **question**:

> How to show *by definition* that $C_n$ and $D_n$ are independent?

---

By the definition of independence of $X_k$, for any finite set of positive integers $I$, the $\sigma$-algebras $(\sigma(X_i))_{i\in I}$ are independent. Eventually, one needs to show that

$$
P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)
$$
for all $A\in C_n$ and $B\in D_n$. 
How shall I go on?

Comment: It's a lot of work to type out so I'll just leave a comment, but a theorem in Billingsley's book is a slight generalization of this with essentially the same proof. I believe in appears in chapter four. If you're looking for just a hint, use the $\pi - \lambda$ lemma.

Comment: Indeed, without knowing what you know and do not know, this is next to impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof of Kolmogrov's zero-one law in Jacod and Protter's *Probability Essentials* (Theorem 10.6) takes this statement for granted and it is sort of "cheating".

The proof of Theorem 22.3 (the zero-one law) in the third edition of Billingsley's *Probability and Measure* gives details about how to prove this statement, which eventually boils down to the Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem in the book (Theorem 3.2 page 42).