# Cardinality of a $\sigma$-algebra over a set of independent random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

**Problem statement**

Let us say that we have some set of independent random variables: $X = \{X_i\}^n_{i=1}$ defined over a probability space of $~(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. I want to understand whether the following holds:

If $\mathcal{F}_X = \sigma\left(\left\{X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n\right\}\right)$, then is it, in general, true that: $\left|\mathcal{F}_X\right| = \sum\limits_{\forall i \in I_n}|\sigma(\{X_i\})|$?

As we know (and as proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909005/independent-random-variables-and-sigma-algebras)), as $X$ consists of independent R.V.-s, then we can state that $\forall i,j \in I_n:\sigma(\{X_i\})$ and $\sigma(\{X_j\})$ are independent. But how to proceed from this fact to the split of the cardinality of $\mathcal{F}_X$?

I would appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

**Related questions**:

1. [Independent random variables and sigma algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909005/independent-random-variables-and-sigma-algebras)
2. [Cardinality of a sigma algebra of two independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829688/is-cardinality-of-sigma-algebra-for-two-independent-random-variables-is-the-sum)

Comment: The comment section to the linked question about the sigma algebra of two independent random variables already contains a counter example. If it doesn't hold for two, then there is no reason to believe that it would hold for general $n$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen oh, that's true, for some reason, I didn't notice it at the first look. It seems, that in the case of mine, the general case can be disproven by a simple counter-example! Thank you for your note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly mentioned by @LeanderTilstedKristensen, it can be seen, that one of the linked questions already contains a counter-example for the case of two independent random variables. It should not be that hard to show then that in general the proposed cardinality relation does not hold!